# the type or namespace component data is missing error in using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.ComponentData; help me how to solve this error?

Tags: c#

i am currently deploying matlab over .net i have included my matlab project dll and mwarray.dll of matlab run-time compiler successfully but when i tried in using component data i have 2 errors one is:

> name space missing using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.ComponentData;

second one is:

> cannot convert type void MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.Mwcellarray in
>   line  cellout = (MWCellArray)obj.braille();

complete code is as mentioned below

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using CsharpMatlab;

using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;

using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;

using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.ComponentData;


namespace MATCsharp

{

 class Program

    {
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        Console.WriteLine("Code For Matlab to C#");

        MWCellArray cellout = null;

        CsharpMatlab.CellExampleApp obj = new CsharpMatlab.CellExampleApp();

        cellout = (MWCellArray)obj.braille();

        MWNumericArray item1 = (MWNumericArray)cellout[1];

        MWNumericArray item2 = (MWNumericArray)cellout[2];

        MWCharArray item3 = (MWCharArray)cellout[3];

        Console.WriteLine("item1 is {0}", item1);

        Console.WriteLine("item2 is {0}", item2);

        Console.WriteLine("item3 is {0}", item3);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }emphasized text
  }
}
```